# How can i integrate a laravel package in my application

Tags: php, laravel, ticket-system

I'm a beginner laravel developer. I need to integrate a laravel package known as "Kordy/Ticketit" into my application.

Such that i can get the packages content to show in my admin panel.

Currently i have installed the system but cant seem to figure out how to integrate it in my admin panel.

Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Just read that package documentation, there you will find all usages information about that package.

Comment: You ask your favorite search engine for "Kordy/Ticketit". You eventually end up on https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit. You read the [Installation (manual)](https://github.com/thekordy/ticketit#installation-manual)

Comment: I read the documentation prior to asking the question. documentation is not clear in terms of integration

Answer (score 0):

Just type in your IDE console

composer require 'kordy/ticketit:0.*'

Answer (score 0):

composer require  is used to include the package in Laravel projects so it can define its all dependencies in our composer file.

Comment: Can you explain why you've posted a second answer to the same question instead of editing the old one?